# Batch process for oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am copying data from one table to another table in the same database using the following query "insert into table select * from table where time_stamp <= (select ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1) from dual)" but i need to restrict it to 1000 rows at a time then commit the changes and continue copying. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: if you need to copy the entire table, try a CTAS (create table as select), and do it in one shot.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you do that? It makes the process slower, harder to code, harder to recover from in the event of an error.

Unless you've got an exceptional reason, commit only at the end. Otherwise you have to write PL/SQL to do it.

Your code should be:

```
insert into table
select *
from table
where time_stamp <= ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1);
```

Comment: that code works perfectly but the number of records is in millions and it is better to do the copying in batches

Comment: @user3274312 - why do you think it's better to do it in batches? ([Here's an example of why Tom Kyte thinks it isn't](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022#4959613293151), which echoes what David said).

Comment: For "millions" I'd be thinking about direct path insert also, if you can get away with locking the table during the insert.

Comment: @alex poole I want to do it in batches because if any error occurs while copying the entire records are going to rollback.

Comment: @user3274312 what sort of errors are you expecting, and if any occurred what would be your plan for determining which records have been inserted successfully, identifying the problem record, and only inserting the others? Have you looked at Oracle's log errors functionality?

Comment: @user3274312 - if any error occurs while copying a batch that will roll back; how will you recover from that position? You can't just restart as you'll get duplicates. If you carry on from the next batch, how will you know which records are missing? Seems like you're just making life harder for yourself. You could also look at an [error logging table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_errlog.htm) so erroring rows are skipped without successful ones having to be rolled back.

Comment: @david alridge i will look into log errors functionality

Answer (score 1):

This is PL/SQL block you can use to achieve your goal

```
declare
  cursor c is
    select *
    from tableName
    where time_stamp <= add_months(sysdate,-1);

  type tbl is table of c%rowtype;

  t     tbl;
begin
  open c;

  loop
    fetch c bulk collect into t limit 1000;

    exit when c%notfound;

    forall i in 1..t.count
    insert into tableName2 values t(i);

    commit;
  end loop;

  close c;
end;
```

Unfortunately I do not know your columns so you can rewrite this part

```
insert into tableName2 values t(i);
```

e.g. like that

```
insert into tableName2(col1,col2) values t(i).col1,t(i).col2;
```

I have not tested, but this is more about an idea how to do it.

Comment: Appending `SAVE EXCEPTIONS` to your FORALL might catch the exceptions(Constraints) and Proceed to next Record. Else it would stop when one exception arises. More details from [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#i49099)